# how to check the password if it's upper case and lower in JFrame JAVA?

Tags: java

this frame will be SignUp frame I faced some problems when I want to check the password if there are upperCase and lowercase letters and the number of digit > 0 and the letters >0, so how can I check the password the entered from the user if there is uppercase and lower case?

and here is the code

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  Boolean passwordcheck= false;
  Boolean namecheck= false;
  String username =jTextField1.getText();
  String password= String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
  String Email=jTextField3.getText();
  int upper=0,lower=0,digit=0;


if (username.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "add name");
    }else if (password.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "add password");
    }else if (Email.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "add email");
    }
    if (password.length() < 8) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password must contain at least 8 characters!");
    }
    else{  
    char[] aC = password.toCharArray();
    for(char c : aC) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
          upper++;
    } else
    if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
          lower++;
    }
    else if(Character.isDigit(c)){
           digit++;
    }
    }

    }
     if(upper>0&&lower>0&&digit>0)
    {
    passwordcheck=true;
    }

     if(passwordcheck==true && namecheck==false){
          try{
                  String query = "INSERT INTO USER_NAME (USERNAME,PASS,EMAIL )VALUES '"+username+"','"+password+"','"+Email+"'";
            prepared=con.prepareStatement(query);
                result=prepared.executeQuery();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "added  ");

          }catch(Exception ex)
          {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "wrong");

          }

     }
```

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Also, [never trust user inputs](https://xkcd.com/327/). And use `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: can you explain more? where i stored the plain text? i have to take the password from the user it's sign up frame

Comment: You store it in plain text in your insert statement ... passwords should always be hashed with a suitable cryptographically strong password hash algorithm. And your code really should care about uppercase or lowercase in the password.

Comment: Second column in `INSERT INTO USER_NAME (USERNAME,PASS,EMAIL )VALUES '"+username+"','"+password+"','"+Email+"'` - that is the plain text user password. SALT and hash it. At a minimum. [Why shouldn't I store passwords in plaintext?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/120540/54684)